# SQLite dataypes lengths?

Tags: sqlite

I'm completely new to SQLite (actually 5 minutes ago), but I do know somewhat the Oracle and MySql backends.

**The question**: I'm trying to know the lengths of each of the datatypes supported by SQLite, such as the differences between a bigint and a smallint. I've searched across the SQLite documentation (only talks about affinity, **only** matters it?), SO threads, google... and found nothing.

**My guess**: I've just slightly revised the SQL92 specifications, which talk about datatypes and its relations but not about its lengths, which is quite obvious I assume. Yet I've come accross the Oracle and MySql datatypes specs, and the specified lengths are mostly identical for integers at least. Should I assume SQLite is using the same lengths?

**Aside question**: Have I missed something about the SQLite docs? Or have I missed something about SQL in general? Asking this because I can't really understand why the SQLite docs don't specify something as basic as the datatypes lengths. It just doesn't make sense to me! Although I'm sure there is a simple command to discover the lengths.. but why not writing them to the docs?

Thank you!

Comment: uhhhh....what exactly are you looking for? the maximum length for char, int etc? it is in the documents...

Comment: yup. maximum length is the accurate question I should have asked for, thanks for it. And I haven't found it, really.

Answer (score 19):

SQLite is a bit odd when it comes to field types.  You can store any type in any field (I.E. put a blob into an integer field).  The way it works for integers is: it depends.

While your application may use a long (64 bits) to store the value, if it is actually <128 then SQLite will only use one byte to store it.  If the value is >=128 and <16384 then it will use 2 bytes.  The algorithm (as I recall) is that it uses 7 bits of each byte with the 8th bit used to indicate if another byte is needed.  This works very well for non-negitive values but causes all negative values to take 9 bytes to store.

Answer (score 9):

In SQLite datatypes don't have lengths, values have lengths. A column you define as TINYINT could hold a BLOB, or visa versa.

Comment: should think about this answer, quite aslept right now but thoughtful. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm completely new to the SQLite documentation, but I found it in less than 30 seconds.

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 0):

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

8 byte >> mix size is max: 9223372036854775807